# Determining max number of clients a person can have on their caseload based on their schedule & client frequency

Tags: integer-programming, operations-research

I'm not sure if it's possible, and to be clear math is not my strong suit (assume I only know basic high school math, and a handful of excel functions). I'm a therapist supervisor, and I've been given a difficult problem to solve from my upper management. I'm trying to see if there's a way to determine the max number of clients a person can have on their caseload based on their schedule & client frequency?

For example, if Sarah works 3 days out of the week, and works 8 hours each day seeing 1hr session appointments for a total of 24 hours seeing clients per week. What’s the max number of clients, of different frequencies, that Sarah can have on her 24hr/3day caseload at any given time?

The frequencies for client appointments are as follows:
Weekly, Bi-Weekly, Monthly, Bi-Monthly, Every 3-5 Months, Bi-Annually, and Annually

Again, not sure if it's possible, but it would be very helpful to have a formula that would allow me to know that *if* a clinician has 'x' number of weekly clients, the max number of OTHER weekly or other frequency clients that clinician would be able to take on given limited hours/days scheduling.

Is this even something I, or someone who knows much more, would be able to standardize in order to apply it to a different clinician/different schedule? Or is this an impossible task that was assigned my way? Please let me know if it is or is not possible, and if so 'how' and if not 'why'. Any assistance would be helpful!

Comment: If a clinician has $h$ free hours/week and a client of a particular type requires $c$ hours/week, then the number of clients of that type the clinician can add is $h/c$. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: It does not make sense to compute separately the maximum number of weekly, biweekly etc. clients because the categories "interfere" with each other. Adding a bimonthly client might prevent you from adding a monthly client and vice versa. Given a population of clients and a set of therapists, and with a bunch of simplifying assumptions, you could use an integer programming model to assign clients to therapists.